# How do I initialize a 2-dimensional parameter array in Verilog-2005?

Tags: parameters, verilog, fpga

I know that this question has been asked before, however, every answer I can find refers to SystemVerilog and its syntax.

I have the following code:

```
parameter NUM_TILES = 2;

parameter [15:0]    TILE_SIZE       [NUM_TILES - 1'b1:0];
parameter [15:0]    TILE_PRV_SIZE   [NUM_TILES - 1'b1:0];
parameter [15:0]    TILE_LOOP       [NUM_TILES - 1'b1:0];
```

I have tried the following, but array literals are not supported in Verilog-2005.

```
parameter [15:0]    TILE_SIZE       [NUM_TILES - 1'b1:0]; = '{16'd4, 16'd4};
```

The defparam statement seems like it would be of some use, but I would need to instantiate my testbench module and employ it from outside the instantiation. I believe my other option is to use module instance parameter value assignment,  e.g.

```
module top_tb UUT #(.TILE_SIZE[i](16'd4),...,...)();
```

but I am trying to stay away from that. Is there some lesser known trick I could use, or will I have to resort to one of the two methods above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is pack your array into a single vector and select a slice of it.

```
parameter [(NUM_TILES*16)-1:0]    TILE_SIZE = {16'd4, 16'd4};
```

Then you can select the parameter with

```
TILE_SIZE[i*16+:16]
```

Comment: This works pretty well. I was defining lookup tables using preprocessor macros to solve my issue, but this is much simpler. Thanks!